# Regular, algebraic and cuspidal for automorphic representations

Tags: automorphic-forms

Given an automorphic representation of the general linear group over a totally real number field, there are 3 properties it might have: regular, algebraic (or "of algebraic type"?) and cuspidal. There are $2^3=8$ possible combinations of which properties are true for a given representation. Can you give explicit examples for each of the 8 combinations?

Can you give examples for the general linear group over $\mathbb{Q}$? If yes, what is the minimum $n$ (as in $\mathrm{GL}_n$) such that all combinations arise?

Comment: the representation corresponding to Ramanujan Delta function is regular algebraic and cuspidal for GL(2).

Comment: @OP there are two notions of algebraic (L-algebraic or C-algebraic). Which one do you want?